# What are the advantages or disadvantages of using pgx vs postgresql as the database type in crowdsec's configuration?

Tags: postgresql, crowdsec

First I had 'postgres' as the db type in /etc/crowdsec/config.yaml but soon realized that 'postgres' was not a valid value so I changed database type to 'pgx' before I noticed that 'postgresql' was an option. I don't see any errors pertaining to pgx but I'm still not sure whether I chose the right driver. I just want to avoid any potential limitations.

Thanks.

Comment: CrowdSec is written in Go; this is related: https://preslav.me/2022/05/13/pq-or-pgx-choosing-the-right-postgresql-golang-driver/